# Excel (Non-VBA): Limit formula on a certain row and continue on the next column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this sample data:

[image]

Assuming I have the formula to combine values of A & B in a new cell (starting from cell E1), how can I limit the formula on the 5th row and continue on the next column (and so on) like on the sample above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following formula can be implemented in Cell `E1` and copied down and across

`=IFERROR(INDEX($A:$A,(ROWS($E$1:E1)/(ROW()<=5))+((COLUMNS($E$1:E1)-1)*5))&INDEX($B:$B,(ROWS($E$1:E1)/(ROW()<=5))+((COLUMNS($E$1:E1)-1)*5)),"")`

In principle, it is the same formula concatenated for two columns.

`INDEX($A:$A,(ROWS($E$1:E1)/(ROW()<=5))+((COLUMNS($E$1:E1)-1)*5))`

which basically does the following:

- Return results from each set of row 1 to 5
- Returns error if formula row exceeds 5 `(ROW()<=5)` portion
- Keeps increasing the base counter as formula is copied rightwards `(COLUMNS($E$1:E1)-1)*5`

Answer (score 0):

Try in `E1`

```
=INDEX($A:$A,ROW()+((COLUMN(A1)-1)*5))&INDEX($B:$B,ROW()+((COLUMN(A1)-1)*5))
```